# Cropping hyperlinks from block of text with PHP

Tags: php, html, text, strip-tags

I have the following **HTML** on my webpage:

```
<p>This is a <a href="http://www.google.com/">hyperlink</a> and this is another <a href="http://www.bing.com/">hyperlink</a>. There are many like it, but <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_Metal_Jacket">this one is mine</a>.</p>
```

Now, I was wondering...

**Is there any way, I can use a PHP function to split this block of text up into an array?**

```
$html[0] = "<p>This is a & this is another . There are many like it, but .</p>";
$html[1] = "http://www.google.com/";
$html[2] = "http://www.bing.com/";
$html[3] = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_Metal_Jacket";
```

So, basically stripping the initial block of text of all hyperlinks and storing them all in their own array element.

Many thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this RegEx to get URL's of html:

```
  $url = "http://www.example.net/somepage.html";
  $input = @file_get_contents($url) or die("Could not access file: $url");
  $regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
  if(preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $input, $matches)) {
    // $matches[2] = array of link addresses
    // $matches[3] = array of link text - including HTML code
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Pachonk. Will this also work if I just use a `$string` variable instead of the $url itself? Thank you.

Comment: If you set "input" = to your html.